# Xlib. Frame responds to input send to client window

Tags: x11, window

I am creating a frame using the following:

```
frame = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, root, x_window_attributes.x, x_window_attributes.y, x_window_attributes.width, x_window_attributes.height + window_bar_height, border_width, border_color, background_color);
XSelectInput(display, frame, SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask);
XAddToSaveSet(display, window);
XReparentWindow(display, window, frame, 0, 20);
XMapWindow(display, frame);

//Map events
XGrabButton(display, Button1, 0, frame, false, ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
XGrabButton(display, Button1, 0, frame, false, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
XGrabButton(display, Button3, 0, frame, false, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
```

Ideally, the mapped events would only work when the user interacts directly with the frame. However, they also work when the user interacts with the client window. In other words, instead of having to drag the frame, I can drag anywhere and it will still move/resize the window.

How can I limit that only to the frame. I thought maybe SubtstructureRedirectMask was the cause of this, but I encounter the same issue after removing it.

Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question arose from my complete lack of understating of Masks and input handling in Xlib. I had to learn this by far too much trial and error and at this point I might start growing a neck beard. Here's the answer for those also struggling and those who wish to remain clean-shaven:

Do not worry about the masks (e.g. `SubtstructureRedirectMask`) for now, just know it is required to receive input.

As for the frame, my original plan was to create a frame the size of the client window plus some more and then offset it. E.g. if the client window is 800px tall, I make the frame 820px tall, offset the client window by 20px, and use the top 20px as  a titlebar. I was hoping the client window would block input to the rest of the frame and only the exposed top 20px would respond to it*. This is not, however the case. The input travels right through** the client window and the entire frame (titlebar area and the client window area) responds to it.

To avoid this issue, and after going through the code and testing with other window managers, I decided to create a separate titlebar window. Now I have `window`, which represents the client window, `frame`, which represents the frame (need this as a parent), and `titlebar`, which represents the titlebar.

The code I previously had has been replaced with:

```
XGrabButton(display, Button1, 0, titlebar, false, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
XGrabButton(display, Button3, 0, titlebar, false, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
```

So now only the `titlebar`, which is positioned above the `window`, cares about the input for moving it around. For resizing and moving the frame and client window, I do some simple math to compensate for everything.